# Email Id capture in reservation process

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, prototype

I have a html page which contains registration form fields like email address and etc. There are fiew steps in registration process. In the first step the form has an email address field.

What I want is if user enters an email address and leave the form for some reasons, after some sort of time like after 15 min I want to capture that email address and send it to server. Because some of them left the reservation process in middle. I want to capture them even they did not complete the reservation process. I just want to capture that email address by using timer or something. I have used onblur() event and written some code. But I need some help to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: ajax, so what have you tried ?

Comment: "I have used onblur() event and written some code" - Can you show that code?  What is the issue that you need help fixing?

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have some idea of using ajax. But I want to fix some amount of time once he enter the email address. If you give solution in proto type frame work, it will help me alot.

Comment: $('customer_email_address').observe('blur', function(event){   
      element = event.element()
      if (element.value != ''){
        // do some time function, for example 15 min. after fifteen minutes automatically some function should fire
      }
   });

Comment: @user1049997 if your new to stackoverflow,acceptign an answer is just as important as posting a question.. see which answer suits your needs or fixes your problem and accept it,its this tick  check mark next to every answer..

Answer (score 1):

You want an ajax call that returns the the email address. This is not perfect but gives you a general idea of what you need to do.

```
// When the document is loaded do something.
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Do something after 5 minutes (300000 seconds)
    setTimeout('captureEmail',300000)
});

function captureEmail()
{
  // Serialize the form data and send to captureEmail.php
  $('#formId').ajax({
    url: "captureEmail.php",
    data: this.serialize(),
    success: function(){
      $(this).addClass("done");
    }
  });    
}
```

Comment: $('customer_email_address').observe('blur', function(event){   
      element = event.element()
      if (element.value != ''){
        // do some time function, for example 15 min. after fifteen minutes automatically some function should fire
      }
   });

Comment: there are lots of ways to tackle the problem you don't need to spam every answer with yours, try putting yours in an answer instead....

Answer (score 1):

There are literally dozens of ways to do this.

If they go from the first to the second step of the wizard, you can capture the email address to a table in the server.   I would do something along the lines of a table that has email address and a unique id for the registration and a time stamp, then you can have a service that polls table and compares it to the completed registration tables and then stores these emails somewhere.

Another option would be a javascript function that on page exit or browser unload fires off an update method that does an insert in to the table.

Or you could use jquery/ajax so that when they leave the email field it does a validation that it is a valid email format and if so fires off an update method  or some combination of the three.

First you need to decide at what points you want to capture the email address and then look at what mechanisms are open to you.  i.e. a post when going from one step to the next.   or ajax/jquery when firing an event on the page.

Comment: $('customer_email_address').observe('blur', function(event){   
      element = event.element()
      if (element.value != ''){
        // do some time function, for example 15 min. after fifteen minutes automatically some function should fire
      }
   });

Answer (score 1):

i'd use "thenetimp" answer but would change these things

-- `setTimeout` should be launched `onkeydown` of the email text box -- as he'll know that some data is there before making an ajax call..

-- checking for the email validity using Regex is best advised before sending the data

calling ajax after every 5 min's regardless of whether data is present or not nor checking on whether data entered is a complete email id or not will not just flood the server with requests but you might end up storing junk values like `ksanads@` and other things.. !!

although,you could check the id's validity once you get the id in the server itself,but its best get valid data from the client rather than overloading ur server with data which might not even be valid..